# How to order this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query that gets products out of a mysql db. It's something like this:

```
SELECT p.name, p.description, p.price, ps.sizename 
FROM products p
JOIN product_sizes ps ON ps.id = p.size_id
```

The sizename this query it fetching, could be S, M, L etc, but also 38, 39, 40 etc.

What I would like now, is for this query, is to order by sizename, but order it so that when the size is numeric, it orders numeric but when it's something like S, M, L, it sorts in the right way, so S, M, L, XL, XXL, and not alphabetical L, M, S, XL, XXL.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT p.name, p.description, p.price, ps.sizename 
FROM products p
JOIN product_sizes ps ON ps.id = p.size_id
order by case when CONVERT(sizename, SIGNED INTEGER) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN CONVERT(sizename, SIGNED INTEGER) 
    ELSE -CAST(-1 AS UNSIGNED) END ASC
, case sizename WHEN 'S' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'M' THEN 2
            WHEN 'L' THEN 3
            WHEN 'XL' THEN 4
            WHEN 'XXL' THEN 5 END ASC
, sizename ASC
```

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a3fb/1/0

Comment: Okay, this looks promising. I'm going to test it out as soon as I'm back home.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by case when ps.sizename in (38,39,40)
              then ps.sizename
              when ps.sizename = 'XS'
              then 1
              when ps.sizename = 'S'
              then 2
              when ps.sizename = 'M'
              then 3
              when ps.sizename = 'L'
              then 4
              when ps.sizename = 'XL'
              then 5
              when ps.sizename = 'XXL'
              then 6
         end
```

You can adjust the numbers for the alphanumeric order like you want

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a `CASE` statement, but I would recommend adding a `SortOrder` column to your Size table, and ordering by that.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   ORDER BY 
        CASE    WHEN sizename='S'    THEN 38 
                WHEN sizename='M'    THEN 39
                WHEN sizename='L'    THEN 40
                WHEN sizename='XL'   THEN 42
                WHEN sizename='XXL'  THEN 44
                WHEN sizename REGEXP ('[0-9]') THEN sizename
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify existing values in order you want, something like that:

```
SELECT p.name, p.description, p.price, ps.sizename 
FROM products p
JOIN product_sizes ps ON ps.id = p.size_id
ORDER BY FIELD(ps.sizename,'S','M','L','XL','XXL',...)
```